# ChartJs React - How do I stop ChartJs from rounding my figures to 3 decimal points on the tooltip?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm having rounding issues with the tooltip in my Line chart for ChartJs. When I hover over my datapoints on the chart, the tooltip displays a rounded version of my data (usually 3 decimal points, or less if there's trailing 0s). Is there a way to stop the auto rounding in the tooltip and show the full number?

Here's my code and a screenshot of the issue.

```
const LineChart = () => {

    const [dataForChart, setDataForChart]=useState<any[]>([1.0023, 1.0231, 1.0347412, 1.03541, 1.0434, 1.04001, 1.0459])
    const [labelsForChart, setlabelsForChart]=useState<any[]>(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July'])
    
    const options = {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display:false
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Price',
          },
        },

      };
      
      const data = {
        labels: labelsForChart,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Price',
            data: dataForChart,
            borderColor: 'green',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          },
        ],
      };


    return (
        <div>
          <Line options={options} data={data} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default LineChart;
```

[Screenshot of the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRws6.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to use label [callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) it can modify your tooltip text

change your options to

```
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display:false
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Price',
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
            return context.dataset.label;
          }
        } 
      }
    },

  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally figured it out with your help!